# QMediaPlayer doesn't work in qt5

Tags: xcode, qt5, xcode4.6, qmediaplayer

I use Xcode 4.6 on Mac OS X 10.8 and Qt 5.1. I want to use QMeduaPlayer class in my application. Here is my code:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMediaPlayer>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QMediaPlayer* pl = new QMediaPlayer();
    pl->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("Crashday.wav"));
    pl->play();
    a.exec();
}
```

But it doesn’t work and in the console I see:

```
objc97058: Class AVFCaptureFramesDelegate is implemented in both /Users/liri/Qt/5.1.1/clang_64/plugins/mediaservice/libqavfcamera.dylib and /Users/liri/Qt/5.1.1/clang_64/plugins/mediaservice/libqavfcamera_debug.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc97058: Class AVFMediaRecorderDelegate is implemented in both /Users/liri/Qt/5.1.1/clang_64/plugins/mediaservice/libqavfcamera.dylib and /Users/liri/Qt/5.1.1/clang_64/plugins/mediaservice/libqavfcamera_debug.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc97058: Class AVFCameraSessionObserver is implemented in both /Users/liri/Qt/5.1.1/clang_64/plugins/mediaservice/libqavfcamera.dylib and /Users/liri/Qt/5.1.1/clang_64/plugins/mediaservice/libqavfcamera_debug.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc97058: Class AVFMediaPlayerSessionObserver is implemented in both /Users/liri/Qt/5.1.1/clang_64/plugins/mediaservice/libqavfmediaplayer.dylib and /Users/liri/Qt/5.1.1/clang_64/plugins/mediaservice/libqavfmediaplayer_debug.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc97058: Class TransparentQTMovieView is implemented in both /Users/liri/Qt/5.1.1/clang_64/plugins/mediaservice/libqqt7engine.dylib and /Users/liri/Qt/5.1.1/clang_64/plugins/mediaservice/libqqt7engine_debug.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc97058: Class HiddenQTMovieView is implemented in both /Users/liri/Qt/5.1.1/clang_64/plugins/mediaservice/libqqt7engine.dylib and /Users/liri/Qt/5.1.1/clang_64/plugins/mediaservice/libqqt7engine_debug.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc97058: Class QTMovieObserver is implemented in both /Users/liri/Qt/5.1.1/clang_64/plugins/mediaservice/libqqt7engine.dylib and /Users/liri/Qt/5.1.1/clang_64/plugins/mediaservice/libqqt7engine_debug.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
QMediaContent media(QUrl::fromLocalFile("Crashday.wav"));
pl->setMedia(media); 
pl->play();
```

Make sure the wav file is in the same directory as the compiled executable. It might be better to connect a slot to [mediaStatusChanged signal](http://qt.apidoc.info/5.1.1/qtmultimedia/qmediaplayer.html#mediaStatus-prop) and start playback from there when [QMediaPlayer::MediaStatus](http://qt.apidoc.info/5.1.1/qtmultimedia/qmediaplayer.html#MediaStatus-enum) equal to QMediaPlayer::LoadedMedia.